# Debug C programs in Python c_types

Tags: c++, python, c

I have developed a library using C++ and C; and the library is working fine with my C++ test program; but it gave me a segmentation fault when the library is used in Python using **c_types.**

Also, **my library works fine under 64 bit OS when I use c_types or C++ test program**, it crashes when I switched to 32 bit OS. And my C++ test program works fine on 32 bit OS.

This is very weird.

Anyone knows how to debug the **Python** and **c_types library** together?

Or do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to use a 64-bit library with 32-bit Python?

Comment: @JanneKarila No, I use 65-bit library on 64 bit OS; and use 32 bit library on 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answer is better:

[runing python in gdb](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb)

In a summary, just run the following:

```
gdb python

//after gdb is running, type the following command
run test_case.py *arguments_of_your_script*
```

gdb will stop when it find a segmentation fault in the python **c_types** library.

After that, just run the common gdb command to examine the memory and registers.

Answer (score 1):

The right is to do it is to launch [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) with [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

An example here : [calling functions returned as pointers from other functions in ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533898/calling-functions-returned-as-pointers-from-other-functions-in-ctypes)